# Possible to create Dimension and Measure groupings in PowerPivot in Excel?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, ssas, powerpivot, olap

In an OLAP tool such as SSAS, I can create dimensions and measures, and Excel respects that grouping. For example:

[image]

Notice the Measures at the top and all the dimension groups underneath it. However, when I try creating these relationships from within Excel, it just groups everything based on the table it comes from. For example:

[image]

The only 'Measures' you can define (if you can call it that) is a calculated field when you click the 'Measures' icon in Power Pivot:

[image]

Is there a way to specific which of the fields are measures and which are dimensions within Power Pivot (Excel)? If not, is there a way to do this in Power BI (I also have that)? And if not, is the only solution for separating these properly doing it in something like SSAS?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to specific which of the fields are measures and which
> are dimensions within Power Pivot (Excel)?

I am afraid , there is no way to specify or rearrange these  in a new created pivot table in Excel.

> If not, is there a way to do this in Power BI (I also have that)?

Yes you could do this in Power BI, by [Analyse Power BI dataset in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-analyze-in-excel#:%7E:text=With%20Analyze%20in%20Excel%2C%20you,datasets%20to%20use%20in%20Excel.). The PBI dataset would separate measures and dimensions  But, you would need to have a Power BI Pro license for this operation.